# how to call user's user and pass

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, joptionpane

I'm creating a very simple login program using `JOptionPane` i want the user to create his/her own username and password and if it's done he/she will proceed to log in but the system will check if the user and pass are matched to proceed. I'm trying to do it and think about the logic behind but there's something wrong I don't know what to do for the system to check if the pass and username are matched to the user input. here is the code how I do it idk if its right thank you in advance for helping

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //LOG IN PANEL

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));

        JLabel createUser = new JLabel("Create your username");
        JLabel createPass = new JLabel("Create your password");

        JTextField textField = new JTextField(12);
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(12);

        panel.add(createUser);
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(createPass);
        panel.add(passwordField);

        int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Create your account",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if (a == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));

            JLabel yourUser = new JLabel("Enter username");
            JLabel yourPass = new JLabel("Enter password");

            JTextField yourUserField = new JTextField(12);
            JPasswordField yourPassField = new JPasswordField(12);

            panel.add(yourUser);
            panel.add(yourUserField);
            panel.add(yourPass);
            panel.add(yourPassField);

            int b = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel2, "Create your account",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (b == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                if (yourUserField.getText(textField).equals(textField) && new String(yourPassField.getPassword()).equals(passwordField)) {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "but there's something wrong" is not a problem description.

Comment: This doesn't compile, does it? `yourUserField.getText(textField)` does not look like an existing method

Comment: yes he does not seem to be accepted and also that new String(yourPassField.getPassword()).equals(passwordField))

Comment: And why do you expect that to work? your are calling the `equals` method of `new String(yourPassField.getPassword())` and your pass a `JPasswordField` as a parameter. Why would those be considered equal?

Comment: you seem to intent to check whether the user has given his name and password twice and whether both the names and passwords match. But you have no concept of creating a new user in a system nor did you provide a logic, to check the credentials against a system. As @f1sh mentioned, you are comparing text with widget instances. That hardly will give you any meaningful result

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check if the username inserted by input is present in your database, if you have a match then you check the password, if all match you can grant the access.
But i don't know if you are searching for this...

Comment: The question owner seem to struggle with his concept. There is nothing mentioned about any database backend. You answer adds more confusion than it could clarify things up